# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTableIfNotExists' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express, knex.js

I have a problem with `knex` and migrating my table, so I do

`knex migrations:make users`, then in the migration file I define:

```
    exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
      return knex.shema.createTableIfNotExists('users', (table) => {
        table.increment();
        table.string('username').unique().notNullable;
        table.string('password').notNullable();
        table.boolean('admin').notNullable().defaultTo(false);
 table.timestamp('created_at').notNullable().defaultTo(knex.raw('now()'));
      })
    };

    exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
      return knex.shema.dropTableIfExists('users');
    };
```

then, I run `knex migrate:latest --env development` and I've got this error:

```
Using environment: development
Knex:warning - migrations failed with error: Cannot read property 'createTableIfNotExists' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTableIfNotExists' of undefined
    at Object.exports.up (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/src/server/db/migrations/20170615170050_users.js:3:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrate/index.js:489:48)
    at Object.tryCatcher (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/petar/Documents/Projects/Daniel/coin_app/display_coin_app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

same error is showing if I run `knex migrate:lates`, my db of choice is `postgres`, I know that he is not creating user at all, the `\d` from my `psql` is showing this

```
user_auth=# \d
                 List of relations
 Schema |          Name          |   Type   | Owner 
--------+------------------------+----------+-------
 public | knex_migrations        | table    | petar
 public | knex_migrations_id_seq | sequence | petar
 public | knex_migrations_lock   | table    | petar
(3 rows)
```

So can someone help me and explain how to solve this, thanks

Comment: Could you add console.dir(knex) to your migration up to see what kind of object is passed to migration? Also which is your knex and node versions and knexfile content to be able to try to reproduce this.

Comment: It was a minor typo, and postgresql was not properly configurated

Comment: shema -> schema